# How to prevent a specific instance of xterm from title changes?

Tags: xterm

If you start `xterm` from the command line giving it a title with the `-T` option

```
xterm -T "my window title"
```

the window title is likely to be overwritten via escape sequences for the shell prompt, other programs' output, etc. Is there any way to prevent the initial title from being overridden?

Comment: Can you mark some answer as accepted if there is one answering your question? (I think the one of @ecerulm from 2014-02-03 does answer your question.)

Comment: I didn’t want to mark my own answer as accepted

Comment: That ist how stackexchange works. Also marking own answers as "correct" is wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control whether `xterm` allows title changes with the Xresources option `allowTitleOps` described in `man xterm`. If you don't want to change the defaults for your user via the `~/.Xresources` you can add Xresources options from the command line using the `-xrm` option:

```
 xterm -xrm "xterm*allowTitleOps: false" -T "my title"
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, it's desirable to keep the original title and allow the applications to add their own title.

That could be achieved with `screen`. If you add:

```
hardstatus string 'blah - [%h]'
```

to you `~/.screenrc`, and start screen within that `xterm`, then the title will always contain `blah`, but the applications will be able to set the part inside `[...]` with the usual `\e[2;...\a` or `\e[2;...\a` escape sequences.